# How to track from which area of ​the website does the users enter a specific page?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I would like to see from which area of ​​my web site does the users enter a specific page.

For instance, I have this category page: /Nike-Shoes. There are many places that the users can enter to this page; Header menu, Main page, Parent category, Footer, Site search...

How can I track how many users entered /Nike-Shoes from header menu, how many of them entered from site search etc.
Besides this, I also want to track how many of them made a transaction.

So I should be seeing the data like this:
/Nike-Shoes > Header menu > 1000 pageviews > 50 transactions
/Nike-Shoes > Site search > 1500 pageviews > 70 transactions

*As a footnote, I have Enhanced Ecommerce implemented.*

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a segment with sequence. Session or users that visited one page or group of pages followed by another page.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply Michele, Could you elaborate how can I do that or direct me to an article?

Comment: Thank you very much Michele.